# Javascript Promise - Recursion with return value - "Remembering Hierarchy"

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise, omnifocus

I am trying to write a "Sync" (partial) plugin for Omnifocus that recreates hierarchical task from [YouTrack](https://www.jetbrains.com/youtrack/). OF provides the ability to call authenticated RESTful API via something called [Fetch API](https://omni-automation.com/shared/url-fetch-api.html) which returns a promise.

**Setup:** For example, this is the hierarchy of tasks in youtrack:

```
Task 1
|____Task 1A
      |____Task 1 A.A
           |___ Task x
```

**Goal**:
My goal is, starting with an `issueId` traverse the tree both ways, all the while knowing your parents when processing each node at each level. For the above setup, let's assume the starting issue is `Task 1 A.A`. For traversing the children, the process I believe is straightforward. Current issue is added to hierarchy and children are recursed with the hierarchy information provided to them:

```
function issueProcessor(issueID, hierarchy = [], level = 0) {
if (level > 4) {
    throw new Error("Too deep");
}
// This returns a promise which would resolve to the JSON object containing API response
issueGet = getIssueFetchobject(issueID);
issueGet.then(function (apiResponse) {
    if (isItMe(apiResponse)) {
        parent = apiResponse.parent.idReadable;
        if (parentAPIResponse.parent.issues.length > 0 && hierarchy.length < 1) {
          /*
          This doesn't work.
          */
            hierarchy = parentProcessor(parent);
        }
        createOFAction(apiResponse.summary, apiResponse.project.name, hierarchy, level);
        // Add yourself to hierarchy
        hierarchy.add(apiResponse.summary);
        var child;
        for (child of apiResponse.subtasks) {
            issueProcessor(child.idReadable, hierarchy,level + 1);
        }
    }
});
}
```

Processing Parent is where my brain breaks and I can't quite get it to work.

```
function parentProcessor(issueID, hierarchy = [], level = 0) {
if (level < -4) {
    throw new Error("Too deep");
}
issueGet = getIssueFetchobject(issueID);
return issueGet.then(function (parentAPIResponse) {
    if (parentAPIResponse.parent.issues.length > 0) {
        return parentProcessor(parentAPIResponse.parent.issues[0].idReadable, hierarchy, level - 1)
    }
    console.log(`${level} : Parents are dealt with, now my turn`);
    h = JSON.stringify(hierarchy);
    console.log(`${level}: Hierarchy is ${h}`);
    createOFAction(parentAPIResponse.summary, parentAPIResponse.project.name, hierarchy, level);
    return hierarchy.add(parentAPIResponse.summary);
});
```

}

Here is the output when calling parent Processor with `Task 1 A.A`:
        `parentProcessor(issueID, []).then(function (x) { console.log(x); })`

> -2 : Parents are dealt with, now my turn
> -2 : Hierarchy is []
> -2 : Creating task Task 1 A.A under

i.e only the oldest parent is processed (Level = -2), the rest are not processed at all. What I expect to see is of course level -1 and 0 processed and finally getting an array like so:

> [Task 1, Task 1A, Task 1 A.A]

My experience with recursion elsewhere tells me I shouldn't actually need a  separate `parentProcessor` function since the operations are very similar, but I am not able to reconcile recursion with the introduction of promises and incrementally adding elements to an Array.